# Program freezes whilst making web request

Tags: c#

So here is my code:

```
partial void runactivity (Foundation.NSObject sender)
{
    string[] links;

    links = new string[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < links.Length; i++)
    {
        email = $"test123{RandomString(10)}@gmail.com";
        links[i] = "http://" + serverIP
            + ":" + serverPort + "/account/register?isAgeVerified=1&entrytag=&ignore=77240&newPassword=test123&newGUID="
          + email + "&guid=597BFBCFA0E1C4195FD6E8392557CD960361878D%22";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < links.Length; i++) 
    {
        var request    = WebRequest.Create(links[i]);
        var response   = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();                    
        var reader     = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Activity++;
        Console.WriteLine ("Account " + Activity + ": " +  responseFromServer);
    }
}
```

Whilst putting say, 50 in the amount, the application freezes, until everything is complete. It definitely works, and the console logging the message from the site is working, but it just freezes, which means I can't do stuff like update text values and strings whilst the action is taking place.

Is there any way I can make it so that the application/UI won't freeze whilst making these web requests?

Comment: async tasks are your friend. Many good tutorials on the interwebz.

Comment: I have searched for it before, but couldn't find anything useful in terms of something that gives a detailed explanation, not necessarily pre-written code. Got any suggestions of what I can use to learn it?

Comment: @AmbitionRotMG Which GUI API are you using?

Comment: This is a Mac, using Xamarin.Mac, the one that comes with Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a method in the background on my Xamarin app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209784/how-can-i-run-a-method-in-the-background-on-my-xamarin-app)