# Navigation.PushAsync on Android impact on button events

Tags: xamarin, button, onclick

I have a Xamarin cross-platform app with a several "PushAsync" flows with button navigation which work perfectly with iOS and UWP, but when on Android, after the initial push, the new buttons on the next page, even though the "XAML" includes enabled "true" arguments, are disabled. What is needed to enable them that is compatible to the two other OS's?

I have changed the sequences of pages to test if the pages will respond.

I expect the pages to proceed to the next page in the flow like they do in iOS and UWP.

Comment: this should just work.  Without knowing more detail about what you're doing it's impossible to say what the problem might be.

Comment: Hi, you can share some code about Android platform, this will be helpful to check where the problem is.

Comment: Jason and Junior,

Comment: Here is the XAML:

'code' <Button IsEnabled="True" x:Name="Button_Next" Text="" Clicked="Clicked_Next" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" IsVisible="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/> 'code'

and here is the associated event code:

'code' await App.PCL.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new AddDevice2());'code'

Comment: I spent the last day rebuilding the UWP and iOS versions. I had just installed the latest Nugets before moving forward with the Android project. In this go around, the iOS version is now exhibiting the same issue as the Android, but the UWP is working fine. The code above is from the shared project.

Comment: @MarcGeorge Thanks for sharing code. However updating in question will be more clearly to check.And your comment not use @ to your want reply people, then they will not know your reply in time.  Have a try with replacing code `await App.PCL.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new AddDevice2())` wtih `Navigation.PushAsync(new AddDevice2())`

Comment: @JuniorJiang Thanks for the formatting pointer.

Comment: @JuniorJiang I just happen to run the iOS version as a binary and not in VS in debug mode and the hanging problem was not present. I don't have the Android version to the point that I can run it as a binary yet, but hopefully soon.

But given the iOS binary result, it appears to be a VS issue of some sort.

Comment: @MarcGeorge Hi ,thanks for replying.You mean this as a binary occurs error in ios, sorry for not understanding too much.

Comment: @JuniorJiang Actually it is when debugging that the transition to the next page problem occurs. As a binary, it isn't present.

Comment: @MarcGeorge When debugging occurs, it's strange. Better with image to explain this ,will be helpful to find reason.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT It appears that the issue was caused by the fact that there was a parallel task for cognitive services that was hung and consuming most of the CPU thus blocking the progression of the page change. Each page had its own interaction with the service as the app is multi-lingual. The CPU usage of VS itself was a factor as compared to just binary.

Comment: @MarcGeorge So this may need to manage threads using in app.Some tasks can  work in background, and UI tasks just can work in UI Thread. Here is a discussion about using task in backgroud for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209784/how-to-run-a-method-in-the-background-only-when-app-is-open-and-running

Comment: @JuniorJiang Thanks again. As soon as I discovered the basis of the problem, I made the necessary thread adjustments and everything is running properly now. Part of the issue that probably made the problem apparent was that the phone I was testing on was older, for backward compatibility purposes, and didn't have same horsepower as the other devices I have been developing and testing on. Problem resolved.

Comment: @MarcGeorge Glad problem be solved.You can update it in answer , then other people will see this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The page was not truly blocked, but delayed in presenting itself by other treads which were looping and consuming CPU cycles. Are you using multiple threads? Can you give them a lower priority and raise the priority of the delayed thread? Or just take them off line? Do so, and see if that enables the page to load.